# How do I draw a vertical dotted line separating two columns?

Tags: memoir, multicol, columns

`multicol` or `memoir` would be preferred. `\columnseprule`, I understand, is responsible for drawing a solid vertical line between columns. Is there a parsimonious way to achieve the following?

```
-----pretext---
###### : ######
###### : ######
###### : ######
###### : ######
###### : ######
###### : ######
-----posttext--
```

Answer (score 8):

Here is a solution

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{memoir}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@outputdblcol}{\vrule\@width\columnseprule}{\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{\textheight}{\dotfill}}}{}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}



\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

This is a preliminary version uing the `multicol` package as requested:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%
\newcounter{mymulticol}
\setlength\columnsep{20pt}
%
\makeatletter
\def\LR@dotcolumn@boxes{%
     \process@cols\mult@gfirstbox{%
       \ifdim\dp\count@>\dimen\tw@
         \global\dimen\tw@\dp\count@ \fi
       \mc@col@status@write
       \box\count@\hss{\columnseprulecolor\tikzmark{middle-\themymulticol}\vrule
              \@width\columnseprule}\hss}%
     \ifdim\dp\mult@rightbox>\dimen\tw@
       \global\dimen\tw@\dp\mult@rightbox \fi
     \mc@lastcol@status@write
     \box\mult@rightbox\stepcounter{mymulticol}\tikzmark{end-\themymulticol}%
}
\newcommand\LRdotmulticolcolumns
    {\let\mc@align@columns
      \LR@dotcolumn@boxes}
\LRdotmulticolcolumns
\AtBeginEnvironment{multicols}{\stepcounter{mymulticol}\tikzmark{start-\themymulticol}}     

\AtEndEnvironment{multicols}{%
\raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{\tikz[remember picture,overlay]{
  \draw[dotted] 
    ([yshift=-17pt]{{pic cs:middle-\themymulticol}|-{pic cs:start-\themymulticol}}) --
    ([yshift=-2pt]{{pic cs:middle-\themymulticol}|-{pic cs:end-\themymulticol}});
}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[4]
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[4]
\end{multicols}
\lipsum[4]
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[4]
\end{multicols}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

The code needs two runs for the dotted lines to reach their final positions

The result:

Comment: Parsimonious enough, but not correct enough. I've been trying to make the vertical line appear dotted.

Comment: @SimonKuang I see. Give me some seconds :)

Comment: @SimonKuang It were 3hours instead of some seconds (and it's still a preliminary solution), but I updated the answer.

Comment: Would it be possible to make this work across page breaks? (e.g. `\lipsum` inside `multicols`)

Comment: @SimonKuang Yes, it's possible, but it requires some more work. When I have the time, I'll update the answer.

Comment: Hi! I was wondering if it was possible to increase the size of the circles and make them larger and/or darker? Thank you so much for this!!!