# Coloured Dotted-Column Separator?

Tags: graphics, formatting, multicol

Is it possible to have a "coloured" dotted columns separator instead of a regular one, to separate the columns in the multi-column page layout?

[image: A dotted column separator]

Comment: Please don't downvote duplicate questions (it's a bit unfriendly, especially for new members).

Comment: I wanted a dotted column separator in some colour. Thanks for posting the link.

Comment: @JVJ --- At least one of the solutions on the linked page can easily be modified to produce coloured dots. If you need more detailed help, then you need to provide more information: e.g. what document class you are using, why the linked solutions don't work for you, etc.

Comment: How to do that with a multicol package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the one of the [solutions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/257718/123129) of the [linked question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/257716/123129) in the comments you can just add `\textcolor{blue}{\dotfill}` and `\usepackage{xcolor}` to get the dots in some color.

**Code:**

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{memoir}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@outputdblcol}{\vrule\@width\columnseprule}{\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{\textheight}{\textcolor{blue}{\dotfill}}}}{}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: What should I modify in the second solution, the one which uses multicol package?

Comment: @JVJ insert the color at `\draw[dotted, blue]`.

Comment: Thanks for this. Can I increase the thickness of the dots as well?

Comment: @JVJ write `thick` in the drawing options.

Comment: Cool! It worked elegantly.

Comment: How can I get columns separators of different colours in a single page itself?